# Hard exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

Is there any algebraic way of solving the following equation for $x$?

$$\frac{3^x+2^x}{3^x-2^x}=7$$

Apparently there is some way of solving this and I heve tried to solve it in a conventional algebraic method without success.

The answer should be:

$$\frac{2\ln(2)-\ln(3)}{\ln(3)-\ln(2)}$$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

$$3^x+2^x=7(3^x)-7(2^x)$$
$$2^x(8)=3^x(6)$$
$$(\frac{3}{2})^x=\frac{4}{3}$$
take $\log$
$$x\log(\frac{3}{2})=\log\frac{4}{3}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Write $$3^x+2^x=7(3^x-2^x)$$ so we get
$$\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x+1=7\left(\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x-1\right)$$ now let $$\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x=t$$
$$t+1=7(t-1)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$3^x+2^x=7\times3^x-7\times2^x\iff 7\times2^x+2^x=7\times 3^x-3^x$$
$$\iff 8\times 2^x=6\times 3^x$$
Can you finish it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Multiply through by $3^x-2^x$ to get 
$$
3^x+2^x=7(3^x-2^x)=7(3^x)-7(2^x)
$$
or equivalently
$$
8(2^x)=6(3^x)
$$
i.e.
$$
2^{x+3}=2(3^{x+1})
$$
or
$$
2^{x+2}=3^{x+1}
$$
which you can hopefully solve by taking logs.

Answer (score 2):

multiply the denominator
$$3^x+2^x = 7(3^x-2^x)$$
distribute
$$3^x+2^x = 7\cdot 3^x-7 \cdot 2^x$$
sum $-7 \cdot 3^x - 2^x$ to both sides
$$-6 \cdot 3^x = -8 \cdot 2^x$$
which simplifies to
$$\left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^x=\frac{8}{6}= \frac{4}{3}$$
so the answer is
$$x= \frac{\ln (4/3)}{\ln (3/2)} = \frac{2 \ln 2 - \ln 3}{\ln 3 - \ln2}$$